# Web Crypto API: how to add passphrase to private key

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api

We use `window.crypto.subtle.generateKey` to generate an RSA key pair.

How can we use the Web Crypto API to add a passphrase to the private key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys generated with WebCrypto are not password-protected.

You could export the key and build a format that supports encryption, like pkcs8 in a PEM file, but to do this it would be needed to use an additional library.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party, but isn't [wrapKey()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey) what you're looking for? It's on the same API and allows you to wrap the key up in a password-protected form, e.g. pkcs8.

Answer (score 1):

@pedrofb is right. If you wanted to do this for better or worse PKCS8 is the right format, here is a link to code that can be used to create such a bag - https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/blob/5b9c35c154c48b232b45cc2a908c88e2f56a8447/src/PKCS8ShroudedKeyBag.js

You should probably also read this: http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=543 which describes some concepts related to key bags that are material.

You may also want to look into using webcrypto in a service worker and exposing an interface over PostMessage to get the operation to take place. This, combined with a non-exportable key, provides some protection from arbitrary use of the key, e.g the attacker can only do what the interface allows.